# How to get selected dropdown option text in other div?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get selected value text in other div?

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select name="Gender" class="form-control" tabIndex="21" ng-model="model.Gender">
      <option Value="-1">-Gender-</option>
      <option label="male" Value="M">Male</option>
      <option label="female" Value="F">Female</option>
    </select>
    <p>Value: {{model.Gender}}</p>
    <p>text: {{model.Gender.label}}</p>
</div>
```

==== in other div====

```
 <tr>
     <td colspan="2">Gender: {{model.Gender}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far

Comment: {{model.Gender}} gives me value of selected option. i.e. M or F and {{model.Gender.label}} gives me blank.

Answer (score 1):

As per your current implementation, you are persisting a string value in `model.Gender` so you can use conditional operator.

```
<td colspan="2">Gender: {{model.Gender == 'M' ? 'male' : 'female'}}</td>
```

Comment: so what happens if i have more option items. say 10? i have to write more conditions for that. is there any other way?

Comment: @JaiminDave, Then I would suggest you to create an array of objects and use `ngOptions` directive

Comment: @JaiminDave, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/pzscka0x/ You can explore it further https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions